# How can I write human-language units as postfixes in Haskell, like `3 seconds`?

Tags: haskell

Ruby has a nice feature that allows to convert numbers to other things, e.g. `3.times` for iteration or `3.to_s` for converting it to a string.

People say Haskell is good for writing natural [DSL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-specific_language)s.

Is it possible to write units as postfixes, e.g. `timeout = 3 seconds`?

Comment: Maybe you should have a look at http://hackage.haskell.org/package/dimensional . They use something like `timeout = 3 *~ seconds` ... but you get all other si units and prefixes from that, too.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

**Yes.**

You can do this with the following simple trick:

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}

instance Num (Integer -> Integer) where
  fromInteger n = \scale -> n * scale  -- return a function that takes
                                       -- a number and returns a number
```

Then you can write:

```hs
seconds, minutes, hours, days :: Integer

seconds = 1000000 -- base unit, e.g. microseconds
minutes = 60 seconds
hours   = 60 minutes
days    = 24 hours

soon :: Integer
soon = 2 hours + 4 seconds
```

---

**How does this work?**

Above we have given a `Num` instance for `Integer -> Integer`, that is for a *function that takes an integer and returns an integer*.

Every type that implements `Num` and has its function `fromInteger` defined is allowed to be represented by a numeric literal, e.g. `3`.

This means that we can write `3 :: Integer -> Integer` - here `3` is a function that takes an integer and returns an integer!

Therefore, we can apply an integer to it, for example `seconds`; we can write `3 seconds` and the expression will be of type `Integer`.

---

**A more type-safe version**

In fact, we could even write `3 (3 :: Integer)` now - this probably doesn't make much sense though. We can restrict this by making it more type-safe:

```hs
newtype TimeUnit = TimeUnit Integer
  deriving (Eq, Show, Num)

instance Num (TimeUnit -> TimeUnit) where
  fromInteger n = \(TimeUnit scale) -> TimeUnit (n * scale)

seconds, minutes, hours, days :: TimeUnit

seconds = TimeUnit 1000000
minutes = 60 seconds
hours   = 60 minutes
days    = 24 hours
```

Now we can only apply things of type `TimeUnit` to number literals.

You could do that for all kinds of other units, such as weights or distances or people.

Comment: ...it's simultaneously beautiful and hideous. Congratulations. Upvoted.

Comment: It's nice to see the answer I was going to give. :)

Comment: To take this to its logical conclusion, see the [unittyped](https://bitbucket.org/xnyhps/haskell-unittyped/) package. It's really awesome about automatically managing units for you, but it has to use a bunch of extensions and the error messages are *absurdly* bad.

Comment: Note that while extending literals like that can make some things look nicer, it also means you'll likely end up requiring more explicit type signatures.

Comment: This is very nice because it allows us to drop the (*), yet one must watch out for expressions like `3 x^2` ....

Comment: ...because function application between `3` and `x` binds more tightly than any infix operator, so it's not possible for this to square the `x` before multiplying by the `3` without brackets. This is the opposite of the way you expect.

Answer (score 0):

If your units are in lower case you can use the TimeUnit type given above.  But if your units starts in Upper case, you would need to define a newtype or data for each unit and define the Num instance for them.   An example of that is in the Basic interpreter
documented here:  http://hackage.haskell.org/package/BASIC-0.1.5.0/docs/Language-BASIC.html